# Provision and configure Azure VM in private subnet (file, remote-exec, cloud-init, etc.)

Tags: terraform, azure, provisioning, cloud-init

([Originally posted to discuss.hashicorp.com](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/provision-and-configure-azure-vm-in-private-subnet-file-remote-exec-cloud-init-etc/14235?u=mloskot))

I’m setting up a basic multi-tier infrastructure composed of two Azure VMs:

1. Web server (VM1) with public IP and private IP (subnet1)
2. Data server (**VM2**) in **private IP** only (subnet2)

Both VM-s are based on the vanilla Ubuntu Linux images available on Azure.

Obviously, it’s very easy to provision (`apt-get`, Bash scripting, etc.) and configure the Web server using the `file` or `remote-exec` provisioners. I have also experimented with the `clout-init` for that purpose.

Questions:

- What is the recommended method to provision and the data server?
- Is `cloud-init` the only option?

AFAIU, the Terraform provisioners running via SSH are not an option because the data server (**VM2**) is not available at public IP.

What I need to do on the **VM2** is:

- install some packages
- upload/edit some configuration files
- download some data files
- start some services

I’m running Terraform on Windows host, so I did not try the Ansible yet, but AFAIU it operates via SSH, similarly to the Terraform `file` or `remote-exec` provisioners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashicorp recommends using provisioners only as a last resort. They recommend using the Azure VM custom_data method, or cloud-init where available.

Ansible would likely be overkill unless you will need ongoing in-place configuration management. But there are ways to make VM2 securely accessible to Ansible or provsioners if necessary.